# Using "try and catch" with creating a new object

Tags: java, exception

So basically I have a class with a constructor, especifically saying, a constructor for states. I can only create a new State if in the constructor I have a city type region(**State has 2 constructors,** both accept name and Region).

The code looks like this:

```
public State(String Name, int Population, Region Capital) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    super(Name, Population);
    if(!(Capital.getRegionType() == RegionType.CITY)){
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.Capital = Capital;
}
```

The type of the region is defined using a Enum class. The problem is when I create a new function in the test class(main class)

```
     Region3 = new Region("BedRock", 23423,RegionType.VILLAGE); //
     try{
        State s2 = new State("Khemed", Region3); // This should not be possible because Region3 is a VILLAGE instead of a CITY 
     }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
     }
     s2.addRegion(Region2);//Doesn´t work - Error
     s2.addRegion(Region1);//Doesn´t work - Error
```

That's basically my problem, the 2 last lines gives me a error saying I haven´t intialized the variable s2.

I tried running the code without "try and catch" to see if the if statement I have in the constructor would work but it doesn´t.

The method "add" is a method defined in the super class of state (Contry) which simply allows to add States to it.

Hope you can help because I can´t see how I can solve this.

**ADDED (Requested to answer my question)**

Class Region:

```
public class Region {
private String name;
private int population;
private RegionType regionType;

public Region(String name, int population, RegionType regionType){
    this.name = name;
    this.population = population;
    this.regionType = regionType;
}

//get Region Type
public RegionType getRegionType(){
    return regionType;
}
```

Enum with Region Type:

```
public enum RegionType {
CITY,
VILLAGE,
TOWN,
```

}

Comment: You should follow the naming rules of java identifiers so it is easier to read your code. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: So, you throw a `IllegalArgumentException`, then what would catch an `EmptyStackException`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `s2` is only defined in your `try/catch` block, try to put the 2 lines in the `try/catch` block.

But the best approach here is to avoid catching the exception `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: I've done that, and fixed the problem with the 2 last lines, now they work properly. But it seems I cannot catch the exception in the "try catch" block, the constructor works fine when it shouldn´t ..

Comment: which try/catch block ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Region3 = new Region("BedRock", 23423,RegionType.VILLAGE); //
 try{
    State s2 = new State("Khemed", Region3); 
    s2.addRegion(Region2);
    s2.addRegion(Region1);
 }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
 }
```

First of all you must put 2 lines in to try/catch block. And your "State" constructor has 3 paramethers. But you are using another constructor(2 params):

```
 State s2 = new State("Khemed", Region3); // 2 params 
public State(String Name, int Population, Region Capital)// 3 params
```

Use with population param like this in try block:

```
Region3 = new Region("BedRock", 23423,RegionType.VILLAGE); //
 try{
    State s2 = new State("Khemed", 123,Region3); 
    s2.addRegion(Region2);
    s2.addRegion(Region1);
 }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
 }
```

Comment: The class State has 2 constructors, one with 2 parameters and other with 3 parameters .. forgot to tell you that will add right away. Do you think that's why it's not working?

Answer (score -1):

In the second code block, `s2` only has scope within the `try` block. Instead, declare `s2` outside of the `try`.

**Edit:** That's what I get for posting too quickly. `s2` statements should be in the `try`.

```
 Region3 = new Region("BedRock", 23423,RegionType.VILLAGE);
 State s2 = null;
 try{
    s2 = new State("Khemed", Region3);
    s2.addRegion(Region2);
    s2.addRegion(Region1);
 }catch(EmptyStackException e){ //You should log this or something
 }
```

Comment: So I've done that and the 2 last lines now work fine, the problem is that the program is not catching the exception and is just letting it happen when it shouldn´t.

Comment: You'll need to post your RegionType code, at the least, and maybe your Region class also.

Comment: Added both, hope it helps